# server connections

Tags: java, sockets, connection, objectinputstream

I'm doing my own server in Java. I need to do one socket connection and receive a lot of object from client. I did it, it works, but I don`t know if this is the best(fastest) solution. Here is example of my code:

```
try {
    serverSocket=new ServerSocket(18234, 1000);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print("Server failed..");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Object x;
ObjectInputStream ois;
System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
Socket connection= serverSocket.accept();
System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());

while(true){
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    x=ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(x.getString());
    if(x.getString().equals("END")) break;
}
```

Problem is, that when I try receive new object, all time I must do new ObjectInputStream.. Is this solution correct? I must do really fast server and all time doing new ObjectInputStream is too expensive in my opinion.

Comment: Learn how to write a server using vert.x.  Why write your own?

Comment: *"Problem is, that when I try receive new object, all time I must do new ObjectInputStream"* , but why you are forced to make a new object in each iteration, why not one single object ?

Comment: because if i dont do this I got exceptions:java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream for the life of the socket, at both ends. Your statement about being obliged to use a new one each object is incorrect.